# jQuery WeekLine value is empty

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the WeekLine Plugin of jQuery and it works greatly, but when I try to get the value of the field (span) in the form, it's always empty.

My HTML:

```
<p>
  <label>Pick a weekday:</label>
  <span id="weekCal" class="weekDays cleanslate">
    <a href="#0" class="selectedDay">Sun</a>
    <a href="#1">Mon</a>
    <a href="#2">Tue</a>
    <a href="#3">Wed</a>
    <a href="#4">Thu</a>
    <a href="#5">Fri</a>
    <a href="#6">Sat</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

My jQuery code:

```
  $("#weekCal").weekLine({
    mousedownSel: false,
    onChange: function () {
      $("#selectedDays").html(
        $(this).weekLine('getSelected', 'descriptive')
      );
    }
  });
```

When I try to call $("#weekCal a").val() it's always return " ". How can I get these values? What am I missing? Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well as far as the selector goes try text() instead of val().

Comment: God damn it.. Thank you very much!